# TextView setText method not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

TextView.setText is not working in the function call. I am passing data in a method ("changeText"). The code does not work. App stops working. When i try to change text in onActivityCreated it works, but it doesn't work when i pass data in a function

```
public class Fragment_b extends Fragment {

TextView tv;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    changeText(90);
}
public void changeText(int data)
{
    tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(data));
}
}
```

Comment: When you say that the app stops working, is an exception thrown? When debugging the code, have you verified that `tv` a valid object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare your mainView as global. Then use that one to look for your views, calling getActivty().findViewById... is not using the same layout as yout.

```
private View rootView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

And then

```
 tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Fragment_b extends Fragment {

       TextView tv;
       @Nullable
       @Override



        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle      savedInstanceState) {
               View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
return v;
           }

       @Override
       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        changeText(90,tv);
       }
       public void changeText(int data,TextView tv)
       {
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(data));
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            changeText(90);
        }
    });
```